# How do I make a child theme I made POST through a 3rd party plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization, forms

I made a custom form in a child theme I am developing. One of the plugins I have installed is Anspress. I want to use my question form instead of the plugin's form. How do I make my form post through the plugin's code? My attempt was fueled by w3schools and a question I found on SO. I linked the action of the form to the location of the php file where the code is that holds the function (or was I supposed to link it to where the form design is located? Not sure) and also used method="POST".

**UPDATE** - I did some more tinkering and I found that I had the link wrong. I fixed it and now get the error:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function ap_user_can_ask() in /home/effilxhy/public_html/WP/wp-content/plugins/anspress-question-answer/theme/default/ask.php on line 13*

This seems to imply that it really is using the plugin's code. Now the problem seems to be that it is checking to see if the user is logged in. Is there a work-around to this or should I take an entirely different approach?

**custom form code**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Main Form */ ?>



<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="/wp-content/plugins/anspress-question-answer/theme/default/ask.php" method="POST">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="addtitle" type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" id="addquestion" placeholder="Find this for me..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" id="addtags">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="main_submit_div" name="submit_button">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="main_submit_button">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Plugin's form**

```
<?php
/**
 * Form and controls of ask form
 *
 * @link http://anspress.io
 * @since 2.0.1
 * @license GPL2+
 * @package AnsPress
 */

class AnsPress_Ask_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('ap_ask_form_fields', array($this, 'ask_form_name_field'));
    }

    public function ask_form_name_field($args){
        if(!is_user_logged_in() && ap_opt('allow_anonymous'))
            $args['fields'][] = array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('Name', 'ap'),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'placeholder'  => __('Enter your name to display', 'ap'),
                'value' => sanitize_text_field(@$_POST['name'] ),
                'order' => 12
            );

        return $args;
    }
}

new AnsPress_Ask_Form;

/**
 * Generate ask form
 * @param  boolean $editing
 * @return void
 */
function ap_ask_form($editing = false){
    global $editing_post;

    $is_private = false;
    if($editing){
        $is_private = $editing_post->post_status == 'private_post' ? true : false;
    }

    $args = array(
        'name'              => 'ask_form',
        'is_ajaxified'      => true,
        'submit_button'     => ($editing ? __('Update question', 'ap') : __('Post question', 'ap')),
        'fields'            => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'label' => __('Title', 'ap'),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'placeholder'  => __('Question in one sentence', 'ap'),
                'desc'  => __('Write a meaningful title for the question.', 'ap'),
                'value' => ( $editing ? $editing_post->post_title : sanitize_text_field( @$_POST['title'] ) ),
                'order' => 5,
                'attr' => 'data-action="suggest_similar_questions"',
                'autocomplete' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'type'  => 'custom',
                'order' => 5,
                'html' => '<div id="similar_suggestions"></div>'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description', 'ap'),
                'type'  => 'editor',
                'desc'  => __('Write description for the question.', 'ap'),
                'value' => ( $editing ? apply_filters('the_content', $editing_post->post_content) : @$_POST['description']  ),
                'settings' => apply_filters( 'ap_ask_form_editor_settings', array(
                    'textarea_rows'     => 8,
                    'tinymce'           => ap_opt('question_text_editor') ? false : true,
                    'quicktags'         => ap_opt('question_text_editor') ? true : false ,
                    'media_buttons'     =>false,
                )),
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => 'ap_upload',
                'type'  => 'custom',
                'html' => ap_post_upload_form(),
                'order' => 10
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'parent_id',
                'type'  => 'hidden',
                'value' => ( $editing ? $editing_post->post_parent : get_query_var('parent')  ),
                'order' => 20
            )
        ),
    );

    if(ap_opt('allow_private_posts'))
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name' => 'is_private',
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'desc'  => __('Only visible to admin and moderator.', 'ap'),
            'value' => $is_private,
            'order' => 12,
            'show_desc_tip' => false
        );

    if(ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key') == '')
        $reCaptcha_html = '<div class="ap-notice red">'.__('reCaptach keys missing, please add keys', 'ap').'</div>';
    else
        $reCaptcha_html = '<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="'.ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key').'"></div><script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl='.get_locale().'&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"  async defer></script><script type="text/javascript">var onloadCallback = function() {
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
          "sitekey" : "'.ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key').'"
        });
      };</script>';

    if(ap_opt('enable_recaptcha'))
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name' => 'captcha',
            'type'  => 'custom',
            'order' => 100,
            'html' => $reCaptcha_html
        );

    /**
     * FILTER: ap_ask_form_fields
     * Filter for modifying $args
     * @var array
     * @since  2.0
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'ap_ask_form_fields', $args, $editing );

    if($editing){
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name'  => 'edit_post_id',
            'type'  => 'hidden',
            'value' => $editing_post->ID,
            'order' => 20
        );
    }

    $form = new AnsPress_Form($args);

    echo $form->get_form();
    echo ap_post_upload_hidden_form();
}

/**
 * Generate edit question form, this is a wrapper of ap_ask_form()
 * @return void
 * @since 2.0.1
 */
function ap_edit_question_form()
{
    ap_ask_form(true);
}
```

Comment: it's better not to work with PHP files in plugin directory. instead of this, you can send the form to the page itself and before showing the form, test if the form is submited

Comment: @mmm How do I do that? I'm new to web dev in general.

Comment: where you show the form is `echo $form->get_form();`. you can replace with `if (isset($_POST["title"])) { /* form is submited */ } else { echo $form->get_form(); }`

Comment: @mmm Please see the question edit. It looks like I got the form to submit, but now the problem is that it isn't recognizing if a user is logged in? I feel like even if I find a way to fix this, anything else that the plugin checks for will get in the way. Is there another approach I can take? Should I consider the alternative of changing the **design** of the form to match mine? The fields are all the same.

Comment: Hmmm... actually, upon looking at this a bit more, it seems to be a question of scope. The error seems to imply that in the linked php file it is calling a function which isn't defined in my custom form....

Comment: You can't target plugin or theme files directly, because WordPress is not loaded in that context. If you search this site for questions regarding form handling, you will find some answers with examples. I know I've answered similar questions here several times.

Comment: You can use ask form widget of AnsPress